# Vue.js about passing data with props

Tags: components, vue.js

[image]

[image]

[image]

I start to learn Vue.js. About passing data to chlid-component, I met a mess. The data isn't shown on the child-component. Why? Somewhere mistake?

Comment: Its better to include the actual code, than screen shot of code, as it is easy to read, as well helps to answer as you don't have to write the whole code again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case), *HTML attributes are case-insensitive, so when using non-string templates, camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-case (hyphen-delimited) equivalents* like following:

```
<child v-bind:child-msg="parentMsg"></child>
```

Comment: Thank you! I ignored this point which is important. It's so bad!